# re.Pattern.findall works wrong

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to match all pattern in a string by `pattern.findall`,but it only works partly

code

```
#--coding:UTF-8 --
import re
import pprint
regex = r"(19|20|21)\d{2}"
text = "1912 2013 2134"
def main():
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    print pattern.findall(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and it print:

```
['19', '20', '21']
```

should it print `['1912', '2013','2134']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) docs,

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

Since your original RegEx had one capturing group (`(19|20|21)`), the value captured in that alone was returned. You can play with that like this

```
regex = r"(19|20|21)(\d{2})"
```

Now we have two capturing groups (`(19|20|21)` and `(\d{2})`). Then the result would have been

```
[('19', '12'), ('20', '13'), ('21', '34')]
```

To fix this, you can use [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group), like this

```
regex = r"(?:19|20|21)\d{2}"
```

which gives the following output

```
['1912', '2013', '2134']
```

Comment: @whatout I have linked another question where the non-capturing group is beautifully explained. Please check that once.

Comment: I've gotten your idea, if `findall` is used to match groups, it will only match what in groups and leave everything else. so if I try `((19|20|21)\d{2})` , the result will be `[('1912', '19'), ('2013', '20'), ('2134', '21')]`

Answer (score 1):

It's working correctly, you're only capturing `19`,`20`,`21` in the capturing group of `(19|20|21)`.

You need a non-capturing group by changing it to `(?:19|20|21)`, as from the documentation.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups

Answer (score 1):

Round brackets indicate matching groups. In your regex, you are looking for two digit numerals which are either 19, 20 or 21.

Perhaps you need this regex:

```
r'19\d{2}|20\d{2}|21\d{2}'
```

This looks for any number starting with 19 followed by two digits or 20 followed by two digits or a 21 followed by two digits.

Demo:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: regex =rr'19\d{2}|20\d{2}|21\d{2}'
In [3]: text = "1912 2013 2134"
In [4]: pattern = re.compile(regex)
In [5]: pattern.findall(text)
Out[5]: ['1912', '2013', '2134']
```

Comment: You have only two elements. So, no need to use range.

Comment: @thefourtheye Agreed. It is extraneous.

Comment: Wouldn't that also match things starting with 10, 11, 29, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be to refrain from `findall()` and instead do

```
print [i.group(0) for i in pattern.finditer(text)]
```

`finditer()` gives you an iterable producing `Match` objects. They can be queried about the properties of each match.

The other solution are more elegant about what the regexps are capable to, but this one is more flexible as you don't have this implicit assumption about the groups which should be returned.